# Can we split a texture into two equal parts in shader code - c# openTK

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, opentk

Is it possible to split an image into two equal parts in opengl shader code? For particular conditions, I have to manage only first half or second half of texture.

Using below code I can perform projection and cropping on entire image(sTexture). Now I want to perform same operations by checking the value of IsSelectFirstHalf. If IsSelectFirstHalf=1.0 then I want to perform the same operations on first half of sTexture (which should be sTexture_FirstHalf). Other wise on SecondHalf of image (sTexture_SecondHalf).

```
      public void CreateShaders()
      {
        /***********Vert Shader********************/
        vertShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(vertShader, @"attribute vec3 a_position;
                                    varying vec2 vTexCoordIn; 
                                 
                                    void main() {
                           vTexCoordIn=( a_position.xy+1)/2 ;                                 
                           gl_Position = vec4(a_position,1);

                               }");
        GL.CompileShader(vertShader);

        /***********Frag Shader ****************/
        fragShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(fragShader, @"precision highp float;

    uniform sampler2D sTexture;   
    uniform sampler2D sTexture_FirstHalf;  
    uniform sampler2D sTexture_SecondHalf; 
    varying vec2 vTexCoordIn;
    uniform float IsSelectFirstHalf;
    uniform float sSelectedCropVal;
    uniform float sSelectedRangeProjection;
    uniform float sSelectedRangeProjectionHorizontal;
    void main ()
    {

vec2  pos  = vTexCoordIn.xy* 2.0 - 1.0;
float b    = sSelectedRangeProjection;//0.5;
float b_Horizontal=sSelectedRangeProjectionHorizontal;//0.5;
float u ;
float v;
float scale = (1.0 + b) / (1.0 + b * sqrt(1.0 - pos.x*pos.x));
float scale_Hriznl = (1.0 + b_Horizontal) / (1.0 + b_Horizontal * sqrt(1.0 - pos.y*pos.y));
u = (pos.x * scale_Hriznl) * 0.5 + 0.5;
v=(pos.y * scale) * 0.5 + 0.5;

 if ( v < 0.0 || v > 1.0 || u < 0.0 || u > 1.0 )
       { 
          discard;
       }

   float c  = sSelectedCropVal;
    if (abs(pos.y) * (1.0 + c) > 1.0){
        discard;}
   if (abs(pos.x) * (1.0 + c) > 1.0){
        discard;}

   vec4  color_NewFrame = texture2D (sTexture, vec2(u, v));
   gl_FragColor = color_NewFrame;

 }");
        GL.CompileShader(fragShader);
    }
}
```

Using Viewport I can display first half and second half with same shader code as above. But the projection and cropping is not working properly then. So that I'm asking is it possible to split the texture in shader code. Then I can use the same shader code as above.

```
  if(IsSelectFirstHalf==1.0)//D1 F1
            {   
                GL.Viewport(new Rectangle(0, 0, glControl.Width * 2, glControl.Height));//FirstHalf
             }
            else 
            {
       GL.Viewport(new Rectangle(-glControl.Width, 0, glControl.Width * 2, glControl.Height));//second half
            }
```

Comment: It's more efficient to have less textures as possible and simply map areas for use. e.g. _sprite sheets_.   Each time you bind to a different texture per frame is a performance hit

Comment: Hasn't the exact same question been asked an hour ago by someone else?

Comment: ...also you want to avoid conditionals in your shader code.  GPUs don't like em.

Comment: @BDL [Can we split a texture into two equal parts in shader code - c# openTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63225136/can-we-split-a-texture-into-two-equal-parts-in-shader-code-c-sharp-opentk)